# Problem with ReWrite Rule order for http to https

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I want to route all requests from http to https, after this route all requests which cause an 404 to route.php script.

But I don't know, how to tell mod_rewrite to 1st use rule one, and then rule two?

My Rule looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT}   !^443$
RewriteRule     (.*)             https://%{HTTP_HOST}/_playground/$1

RewriteCond     %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT}   !^443$
RewriteRule     (.*)             https://localhost/_playground/route.php?to=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_rewrite follows the sequence of the rules:

> The rewriting engine loops through the ruleset rule by rule (RewriteRule directives) and when a particular rule matches it optionally loops through existing corresponding conditions (RewriteCond directives)

ref here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html

and you can use flags to further tuning your rules:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_flags.html